# How to download Maven dependencies into a local repository, only from pom.xml, not from Maven itself

Tags: java, maven

What I'd like to do is similar to the command below. The difference is that I don't want downloading dependencies of Maven itself.

`mvn -f some-specific-pom.xml dependency:go-offline -Dmaven.repo.local=/some/specific/local/repo`

In other words, I'd like Maven to use its own dependencies already in `~/.m2` for itself, and to download dependencies from `some-specific-pom.xml` into `/some/specific/local/repo`.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Using other tools is fine: such as Gradle. But, I'd like to keep the target directory (`/some/specific/local/repo`) structured as a Maven repository.

---

Once I run the command above for a new directory, it starts to download bulk of dependencies of Maven itself, such as `maven-plugin-api-2.0.6.jar`, `maven-artifact-manager-2.0.6.jar`, `plexus-utils-3.0.5.jar`, .... I wanted to skip the bunch of downloads.

Comment: Use parameter `-o` to force offline model. For example: `mvn clean install -o`

Comment: What is the purpose of that? What kind of problem are you trying to solve...

Comment: I know it's really a special case, not a normal usage, but the above is the problem I want to solve. We're building a kind of a plugin system which is loaning Maven's protocol. Wanted to build a local Maven repository which includes just our plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've solved this problem myself with Gradle and https://github.com/tehlers/gradle-download-dependencies-plugin. The `downloadDependencies` plugin helped this situation of mine. Thanks much to the author!

As my situation was a bit more special (I needed to download multiple versions of a same artifact), I've modified the Gradle plugin a bit, though.

Comment: Any equivalent for maven?